# Why are users in a hurry to give an answer on stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, answers, unanswered-questions, policy

Hi Everyone, 
I am a relatively new user in Stack Overflow. Using the website, I have noticed that some people generally give an answer to your question within minutes, no matter how complex it is . In several cases, I have also found the answer to be inaccurate and lacking in detail.
I think Stack Overflow should discourage such activities by allowing the asker to award negative points to the first answerer if his answer is REALLY inaccurate.

Comment: Um... we do that already. See the big "up" and "down" arrows to the left of answers? There's nothing to prevent the asker from deploying them on the first answer.

Comment: ... or anybody else, for that matter! That is how Stack Overflow works - or is supposed to work.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: Well, you need to have a reputation of atleast (>=) 125 to downgrade a answer. Being a relatively new user-- as mentioned in the question-- I dont have that and hence have to bear the inaccurate answers. Anyways, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: ~ Then flag it for mod attention or come over here and gripe about it `with a link to the question` and we'll take a look and downvote and flame 'em for you ;)

Answer (score 7):

Because users are in a hurry to **get** an answer.

Comment: Quick *correct* answers will rake in the points.  Quick *incorrect* answers may get some votes initially but generally end up supplanted by better answers and down-voted.

Comment: to be clear, last comment wasn't a critique of the answer, just elaborating regarding OP's concerns

Comment: @bemace: Quick, *correct-looking* answers will rake in the points. :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Add a bit of <strike>water</strike> jQuery and maybe flaxseed</strike>

Expose to fresh air for 10-15 minutes. Keep dry.

Comment: Had to look that one up.

Comment: +1 for water but -1 for flaxseed.  Maybe you meant sunflower?

Comment: @Aarobot you can use egg yolk as an alternative.

Comment: The hose is not long enough for that.

Comment: @Aarobot you need to do this on a *wooden* surface and the hose's length won't matter.

Comment: But then how will I get it all into a single party balloon?

Comment: *Single* party? I thought they stopped using those in the sixties.

Comment: Kinda surprised this answer hasn't been edited yet. :D

Comment: I second @Jon's comment. You should totally drop water and use MooTools.

Comment: +1 for fixing the awful misspelling. It's a common typo, but still.

Comment: /me is clueless: sourdough?

Answer (score 2):

No, you're on the wrong end here.  Stackoverflow is the strongest gathering of subject experts that have ever been collected at one site.  Easily by a factor of 5 from what's done before.

Possibly the real problem is that the questioner didn't formulate his question really well.  That's a common problem, it's difficult to ask a good question when it is vetted by so much talent and expertise.  But do not ever hesitate to post your interpretation of the Real Question, the OP will be thankful for having your insight.  It actually *does* take somebody that thinks like the questioner to see the real question being asked.  Experts can be powerless at times like that.